# what protocol does the bluemix secure gateway and client use to communicate?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I see from this article that there is a gateway tunnel created between client side and server side.

Would it be safe to expose the secure gateway client to all?

Answer (score 1):

The Secure Gateway Client establishes the connection to the Secure Gateway Server over HTTPS using TLSv1.2.  Once this connection is established, the SG Server will set up the listeners for your gateway's destinations on the associated cloud host:port combinations (details dependent on the configuration of each destination).  Connecting to these listeners is the only way to pass information from the public network via Secure Gateway to the private network where your SG Client is located.

Comment: Thanks Galen. Whenever a cloud app wants to send any information to a system residing in private network,it will address the data to the cloud host and port. I'm assuming the listeners are residing on the SG server for the associated cloud host and port. Is that correct? How does the listener push the information to the SG client? Is it a push or a pull model?

Comment: Unable to edit my comment - Where do these listeners reside and how is data getting pushed to the SG client?

Comment: The listeners are on the SG Servers, that is correct.  The persistent connection allows bi-directional data flow between the SG Server and the SG Client -- this is the route used to send requests to on-prem and receive responses from on-prem.